# Find available range in Excel in JS API

Tags: excel, office-js

I have a requirement in my add in where I need to insert a table in Excel. But I need to know if the available cell range is empty for my table to insert there. So I have to check that if my cursor is at A1, do we have available space from A1 to A15 and there is no existing data there.

I tried getRangeByIndexes() function but this just gives a range. I can't find a function that returns a boolean for my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Excel will always have "space" to insert data/table. I guess you want to make sure the cells are in fact empty before inserting table? If so, you can get [getSelectedRange()](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/workbook.md#getselectedrange) API and use [getOffsetRange()](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/range.md#getoffsetrangerowoffset-number-columnoffset-number) to select both the selected range (load just the address and values) and the range associated table dimension (load just values). You can then check to make sure values are empty before inserting. 
Another way could be to check `worksheet.getUsedRange()` to ensure the used range is just A1 (empty worksheet). This only works if you are ensuring that the whole worksheet is empty (not just the table's address).

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways of doing this.  I think the best one is to use a combination of `getSelectedRange`, `getAbsoluteResizedRange`, and `getUsedRangeOrNullObject`

```
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    let numRows = 10;
    let numColumns = 3;
    let range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange().getCell(0, 0).getAbsoluteResizedRange(numRows, numColumns);
    let usedRange = range.getUsedRangeOrNullObject(true /*valuesOnly*/);
    await context.sync();
    if (usedRange.isNullObject) {
        console.log("The range is empty");
    } else {
        console.log("Sorry, it's already taken")
    }
});
```

You can try this snippet live in literally five clicks in the new Script Lab (https://aka.ms/getscriptlab). Simply install the Script Lab add-in (free), then choose "Import" in the navigation menu, and use the following GIST URL: https://gist.github.com/Zlatkovsky/4835778375bb5f5b9d49bff4f5d522f0.  See [more info about importing snippets to Script Lab](https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/blob/master/README.md#import).

The objects returned by `*OrNullObject`-sufficed methods are a bit unusual.  If you've not run into them before, I recommend you read about it [in our docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-advanced-concepts#42ornullobject-methods).  I also go into great detail about it in my book, "[Building Office Add-ins using Office.js](https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins/)" (with all profits to [charity](http://buildingofficeaddins.com/charity)), in a chapter entitled "9. Checking if an object exists".